# Creating a List of strings where the parameter name is also the value name

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

I'm using System.Reflection quite a lot within an app I'm writing and was wondering if there is a way to do this task.

I have a method as part of a library

```
public static string MakeEvent(string Param1, string Param2, string Param3, string Param4)
```

within this method I have a List which is set like this

```
var list = new List<string>{"Param1", Param1, "Param2", Param2, "Param3", Param3, "Param4", Param4};
```

as this is a library, there are an awful lot of these style constructs.

Is there a way that I can take the string representation of the parameter name being passed in (for example Param1), feed that into the list and follow it by the variable itself? And further to this, is it possible to use something like

```
public static string MakeEvent(params object[] objectData)
```

to replace the list of string parameters being passed in?

I've not seen this done before, but there given the cool stuff possible in .NET, it would not surprise me if you can.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this to me. If `List<myClass> classItems = new List<myClass>();` and then each item is essentially myClass.Name and myClass.Value but the label and the value are identical you would want to half it...? Easier to read, maintain and use...

Answer (score 2):

You can't possible get the variable names used as arguments to a function call - what would happen if they weren't variables at all?

The closest think to what you're trying to do I can think of would be an anonymous object:

```
new { Param1, Param2, Param3 }
```

This is shorthand for:

```
new { Param1 = Param1, Param2 = Param2, Param3 = Param3 }
```

You can then use reflection to find them out. I'm not sure if the order is guaranteed though - do you need that?